# How to View an an external object in Geometry Nodes

Tags: geometry-nodes

I am learning Geometry Nodes. In this example I am using 'Mesh Boolean'. Mesh 1 is a sphere. Mesh 2 is a cube. I have brought the cube into the node with 'Object Info'. I will move on to more complex meshes so I don't want to simply add a primitive cube mesh.
Everything works as expected, BUT how do I view the cube as it is moved with the 'Transform Geometry Node'?

[image: The current node set up]

[image: What I can see...]

[image: Everything]

Answer (score 4, accepted):

[image]

you could just double the cube and transform both via transform geometry nodes. Then control the translation via a combine vector node.
A mesh to curve node makes the operation even more visible (i think).

Comment: Beautiful. It works perfectly. To complete my understanding, could you please tell me why you changed Original to Relative in the 'Object Info' node?
(I have read the docs:
https://docs.blender.org/manual/en/latest/modeling/geometry_nodes/input/scene/object_info.html#properties
but I am none the wiser!)

Comment: original means: origin point will be moved to 0/0/0. I assumed, you want the relative position, so if you move the cube somewhere else your node tree would still work. It makes no sense as it is now (if you move via transform geometry) but if you would like to animate the cube outside GN via keyframe, the rest would still work.  so yeah...as it is now it is useless ;)